# Push notifications on React Native from NodeJS event

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, push-notification

I have a React Native app (Android to be more specific) and I'm using NodeJS on the server-side.

I'm using cron jobs in the server to set up alarms, so when they trigger, you get a message in the app via sockets, but I'm looking how to set up push notifications so you can get a notification even if the app is closed, I've read several tutorials but can't find a proper way to do it using NodeJS, like when the cron job triggers, a push notification is sent to the client.

What's the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share any code samples and specific errors.

Comment: Is not about debugging, is that I can't find any tutorial or example that uses push notifications the way I want them.

Comment: Using expo or not?

Comment: No, I'm not using expo.